# Simulated Microarray data

Tags: r, dataset, simulation, microarray, synthetic-data

I would like to generate synthetic microarray data sets for simulation purposes.
The web and literature search so far returned the following:

1. [Microarray Simulator](http://csb.cs.tut.fi/resources.php) - It provides Matlab skripts to simulates all the pipeline before the actual values. For my needs it is overpowered - and I also would like to have some methods in R.
2. Simulated two-sample microarray data from [OCplus](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/OCplus.html) - is actually exactly what I'm looking for. It provides methods for producing synthetic two class data and it is in R!

But I'm interested in further methods for creating synthetic/simulated microarray data. Especially for more than two classes. And maybe more skrews and bolts to tinker with. I tried to find some methods in `limma`, but I wasn't succesful.

Does anybody know or can recommend an R package/library for creating simulated/synthetic microarray data set ?